# Include synonyms in solr without using synonyms.txt

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-6

I am using Drupal Apache Solr for my searches. in this I found a synonyms.text file in which you can include synonyms manually for the words u want.

But as I suppose it would be very hard to include synonyms manually for each word as my application has large data.

What I want to achieve is as following in my search results:

> when the user will search for allu in place of potato, we will display potato as 1st result.
>
> Another example: when user will search for 'raw apple' then we'll display 'apple' as 1st record because 'raw apple' is synonym of 'apple'.

But the problem is 100K records and each record has 4-5 synonyms. Entering them manually is not possible.

Another issue is If I want to make changes to synonyms of particular record I will have to do it manually which is time consuming as well.

I want to know is there any other option so that I need not to enter synonyms manually?

Comment: Why not just generate your synonyms.txt file programmatically from your database or wherever your 100k rows are?

Comment: @Ansari the problem is if I have to update 30 records, how I will update those in synonyms.txt?

Comment: You can just regenerate the file again, it'll take a few seconds. The bigger problem I imagine would be re-indexing each time that happens.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is close to search engine optimization. Also you may have a tough time managing the synonyms manually.

Follow what Indian e-retail sites are doing to accomodate synonyms. For example e-retail stores have adapted by renaming a certain product **[belly shoes](http://www.jabong.com/women/shoes/womens-belly-shoes/shoes/)** as shoppers tend to mispronounce and misspell "**ballet**". They wouldnt have anticipated it before users actually searched for them.

So **log all requests which return few results** (and otherwise dissatisfy customers). Maintain a list of synonyms in the index. And include these synonyms in the keywords when adding a new product: when adding a product `x y z`, automatically fetch all synonyms to `x`, `y` and `z` and let your data entry guys choose from them.

```
'type':'synonym'
'terms':'ballet','belly'

'type':'synonym'
'terms':'potato','allu','aloo'

'type':'product'
'name':'home garden potato planter'
'keywords':'allu','aloo'

'type':'product'
'name':'aloo mutter fry mix'
'keywords':'potato','allu','cheese'
```

Answer (score 0):

we can maintain a list of synonyms in the index. and include these synonyms in the keywords by adding a new product. when adding a new product a b c it can fetch synonyms to a, b and c.

'type' :product'
'name' :'monety carlo shirt for men'
'keywords' : 'montey carlo', 'shirts'

Example: [Online Shopping Store](http://www.onlinesuvidha.com) Has adapted to rename certain products and misspell name.